# Upgrading from Play Services 7.5 to 7.8 - GCM APIs not found

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

Upgraded from 7.50 -> 7.8.0, then Android Studio could not find the GCM classes. Reverting to 7.5.0 fixes the issue.

`7.5.0` lets Android Studio locate `InstanceID` and other GCM classes, but after upgrading the version number to `7.8.0`, those GCM classes cannot be found.

using the gradle code below. `playServicesVersion = '7.5.0'` works, but `playServicesVersion = '7.8.0'` does not.

```
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:$playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$playServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServicesVersion"
```

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: No, everything is fine

Comment: Not working to me too.

Comment: exactly same issue. Clean Project help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really no idea why this was happening - but after switching to build tools 23, it worked.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Not apparent why.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i was attempting to run the gcm-demo sample available on following link :
git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git

What i experienced was that when ever running on emulator it was complaining of playservices out dated even though i had API 22 Google API Emulator and latest play services. I tried downgrading the play services version to 7.5 but it failed compiling even though my SDK had that version. Eventually, i solved the problem by downgrading the API 21 and moving to Google API 21 Emulator image. It has 7.8+ version of Play Services and it executed well on that version.